# Python: Removing white spaces between two string entries in a list

Tags: linux, list, python-2.7

This is the code:

```
import os
import re
import subprocess

current_setting = list()
with open('/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf' ,'r')as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            current_setting.append(line.strip())
current_setting.remove('')
print current_setting

desired_setting = list()
with open('ctl_alt_del', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        desired_setting.append(line.strip())
print desired_setting

if set(current_setting) == set(desired_setting):
    print 'The file has to be modified'
```

I am getting output as:

```
['start on control-alt-delete', '', 'exec /sbin/shutdown -r now "Control-Alt-Delete pressed"']
['start on control-alt-delete', 'exec /sbin/shutdown -r now "Control-Alt-Delete pressed"']
```

The two lists are identical except the white space between two entries of the first list.
Because of that, the comparison is giving false value.
How to remove that white space? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: oops!! thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stripping empty lines; skip them with a simple `if`:

```
with open('ctl_alt_del', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            desired_setting.append(line.strip())
```

You can simplify those lines with a list comprehension:

```
with open('ctl_alt_del', 'r') as f:
    desired_setting = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
```

(no need to use `desired_setting = list()` before these lines now).

Alternatively, filter the lines after the fact:

```
desired_setting = filter(None, desired_setting)
```

or

```
desired_setting = [line for line in desired_setting if line]
```

Comment: You might want to think about not doing the `.strip()` action twice.  Imperative version can use a variable, but doing this in the functional version (list comprehension) is tricky.

Comment: @Alfe: In the list comprehension, that is going to be tricky, and not worth it really.

Comment: Yeah; the missing `let` of Python ;-)  One could use sth like `desired_setting = [strippedLine for line in f for strippedLine in [line.strip()] if strippedLine]`, but that's a hack.

Comment: Exactly; I was trying to minimise the difference between the loop and the list comp here.